# snow leopard issue when installing rails 3.0.3 with RVM

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, rvm

I have installed ruby via RVM. Installed rails into ruby-1.9.2-head@rails_3_0_3 and set it to default to use:

```
monster:gems gtheys$ rvm use ruby-1.9.2-head@rails_3_0_3 --default
```

Some additional information:

```
monster:gems gtheys$ ruby -v
ruby 1.9.2p174 (2011-01-28 revision 30696) [x86_64-darwin10.6.0]
monster:gems gtheys$ which gem
/Users/gtheys/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-head/bin/gem
monster:gems gtheys$ rails -v
/opt/local/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/1.8/rubygems.rb:779:in `report_activate_error': Could not find RubyGem rails (>= 0) (Gem::LoadError)
    from /opt/local/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/1.8/rubygems.rb:214:in `activate'
    from /opt/local/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/1.8/rubygems.rb:1082:in `gem'
    from /opt/local/bin/rails:18
```

What do I need to do. I see when I want to use rails it goes to to the wrong location...

**UPDATE**

I installed the gem Bundle and afterwards reinstalled rails 3.0.3 and now it seems to work :)

```
monster:~ gtheys$ rails -v
Rails 3.0.3
monster:~ gtheys$ which rails
/Users/gtheys/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-head@rails_3_0_3/bin/rails
monster:~ gtheys$
```

Fun solving your own problems :)

Comment: You're really better off avoiding RVM all together if you can. It has no end to problems and will even delete your entire Ruby install randomly sometimes. A better solution is to install each version you want to use with Homebrew and set the path and create soft links for the main executables. You can do this easily with a batch file or even, appropriately, a Ruby script.

Comment: @Mike Bethany - could you elaborate please? I've been using RVM for almost a year perhaps and no problems whatsoever - both Linux and Mac OS X.

Comment: You should post your update as an answer and accept so the question does not remain open.

Comment: Put the answer but have to wait until tomorrow to approve it ;)

Answer (score 0):

I installed the gem Bundle and afterwards reinstalled rails 3.0.3 and now it seems to work :)

monster:~ gtheys$ rails -v
Rails 3.0.3
monster:~ gtheys$ which rails
/Users/gtheys/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-head@rails_3_0_3/bin/rails
monster:~ gtheys$ 
Fun solving your own problems :)

Thanks @tomeduarte for the tip